# Permutation group of a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If we let $G$ be a finite permutation group of a finite set $X$ and assume that $G$ has exactly 2 orbits of the same cardinality, how can we show that there is some permutation in G that has no cycles of length one.

I think assuming otherwise gives you that each element of $X$ is in its own orbit, but half of all the orbits are equivalent? Not really sure how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Is the assumption that there exist only two orbits, which also have the same cardinality? or that it has many orbits, all with different cardinalities except two orbits that match?

Comment: Could you provide some context please? Where does this question come from, and what makes you believe that it is true?

Comment: "no cycles of length one" I'd call "no fixed points". [Burnside's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) tells you that the elements of your group have in average 2 fixed points. Looking at the identity you get exactly one element $x$ with two fixed points (all others have one). How many fixed points do the conjugates of this element $x$ have? Now consider that the centralizer of $x$ in $G$ acts on the set of fixed points of $x$.

Comment: @j.p. I don't follow your argument about there being only one element with two fixed points.

Comment: [this comment removed after noticing the question has been repeated several times, and is therefore probably homework]

Comment: @AlastairLitterick If you can solve it, then perhaps you could provide some hints!

Comment: @DerekHolt A certain subgroup of $\text{Sym}(2)$ provides a very easy counterexample to this statement!

Comment: @AlastairLitterick Yes, OK, but let's assume that $|X|>2$. The claim might be true, but I don't see how to prove it. It might help if one of the people asking the question would reveal where it comes from.

Comment: More generally, doesn't the image of $S_{k} \times S_{k} \hookrightarrow S_{2k}$ give a counterexample?

Comment: No, that had lots of fixed point free elements., like the product of two $k$-cycles.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Isn't $|G| = \sum_{g\in G^\#} |X^g|$ and every element $g\ne 1$ has at least one fixed point? ($G^\#$ is $G$ without 1)

Comment: @DerekHolt of course. I managed to change the problem I was working on in the course of extending my example...

Comment: Some flimsy numerical evidence suggests that if $G$ has two orbits of order $k$, then $G$ has at least $k-1$ fixed-point-free elements.

Comment: @j.p. Not unless $|X|=|G|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Ups, sorry. You're right, of course.